# jquery -- Have collapsing div start collapsed

Tags: jquery, html

I have a collapsing div that works perfectly fine but it starts expanded.

How can I get the div to start collapsed?

Also, how can I get the "Learn More" button to change its text to "Hide" when the div has been expanded?

```js
$(function(){
    $('a.togglebtn').click(function(){
        $('#myContent3').stop().slideToggle(500);
        return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<div>
<a class="lead p-color learn-button togglebtn">
  <small>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">
    </span>&nbsp;Learn More
  </small>
</a>
</div>

<div id="myContent" class="row row-offset" style="margin: 0 30px">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="lead caption text-center">
      <h3 class="h-color">Profile</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img style="height: 100px; width: auto;" class="img-circle" src="images/logo-bunny.png" alt="Thumbnail">
    </div>
    <div class="lead caption">
      <p class="p-color"><small>Some sample text. Some sample text.</small></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Slightly changed your code. Try this.

<div>
<a class="lead p-color learn-button togglebtn">
  <small>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">
      </span>&nbsp;<span id="toggleText">Learn More</span>
  </small>
</a>
</div>

<div id="myContent" class="row row-offset" style="margin: 0 30px">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="lead caption text-center">
      <h3 class="h-color">Profile</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img style="height: 100px; width: auto;" class="img-circle" src="images/logo-bunny.png" alt="Thumbnail">
    </div>
    <div class="lead caption">
      <p class="p-color"><small>Some sample text. Some sample text.</small></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


$(function(){
    $('a.togglebtn').click(function(){
        if($("#toggleText").text()=="Learn More"){
            $("#toggleText").html("Hide")}
        else {$("#toggleText").html("Learn More")}
        $('#myContent').stop().slideToggle(500);
        return false;
    });
});


#myContent{display:none;}
```

Hope this is the one you have expected.

Comment: Worked just as I was trying to do. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you need to do this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Collapsible Div</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<a class="lead p-color learn-button togglebtn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myContent">
  <small>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">
    </span>&nbsp;Learn More
  </small>
</a>
</div>

<div id="myContent" class="row row-offset collapse" style="margin: 0 30px">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="lead caption text-center">
      <h3 class="h-color">Profile</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img style="height: 100px; width: auto;" class="img-circle" src="http://placehold.it/100x150" alt="Thumbnail">
    </div>
    <div class="lead caption">
      <p class="p-color"><small>Some sample text. Some sample text.</small></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Just add data-toggle="collapse" and a data-target to element `<a>` The data-target attribute takes your usual css selectors (id, class, name etc). The `.collapse` is set to "" which starts collapsed.

Check here for more info: [w3schools](https://goo.gl/RhIH5D)